# Laplace transform of a piecewise function

Tags: calculus, laplace-transform

I'd like to compute the Laplace transform of the following function:

$$f(t) = \begin{cases}
0,& \mbox{if} \quad 0 \leq t \lt \pi \\
\sin(t), &\mbox{if} \quad  t \geq \pi
\end{cases}$$

Could someone please provide some pointers?

Thank you!

Comment: Just integrate from $\pi$ to $\infty$ the branch $f(t)=\sin t$ of $f$ as the integral from $0$ to $\pi$ is...zero (the function to be integrated is equal to zero).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use the shifting property of the Laplace transform. Your function is

$$f(t)=\sin(t)u(t-\pi)=-\sin(t-\pi)u(t-\pi)=g(t-\pi)$$

with $g(t)=-\sin(t)u(t)$. The transform of $g(t)$ is a standard result that can be found in any Laplace transform table:

$$G(s)=-\frac{1}{s^2+1}$$

and by the shifting property

$$F(s)=e^{-\pi s}G(s)=-\frac{e^{-\pi s}}{s^2+1}$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: by definition
$$\mathcal L(f)(s):=\int_0^\infty f(t)e^{-st}dt= \int_0^\pi 0\cdot e^{-st}dt+
\int_\pi^\infty \sin t e^{-st}dt=\int_\pi^\infty \sin t e^{-st}dt.$$

Using $\sin t=\frac{e^{it}-e^{-it}}{2i}$ you can arrive at the answer.